# How to remove NavigationBar Right space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiedgeinsets

I'm playing with Navigation Bar Buttons I need a button from right edge with 0 space, after google search i found below code

```
 self.filterButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 45)];
[self.filterButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIImage *buttnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chemistry-filter"];
[self.filterButton setImage:buttnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.filterButton];

UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -25;
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,btn2, nil] animated:YES];
```

But unfortunatly in iOS 13 negativeSpacer not working. can anybody suggest me solutions.

Attached screenshot here [image]
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot how does it look ?

Comment: please check attached image

Comment: So u don't want the white space as it is seen on the right side of the button right ?

Comment: yes white space i want to remove

Comment: try with image aspect mode as fill

Comment: you can make use of constraints also, like leading anchor, trailing anchor, bottom anchor and top anchor. And that way it attaches to the corner

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this easy way, Let's define the width of space BarButtonItem to be width of `self.view.frame.size.width - width of the button`.

```
self.filterButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 45)];
[self.filterButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIImage *buttnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chemistry-filter"];
[self.filterButton setImage:buttnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithCustomView:self.filterButton];

UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil 
action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 45; // As 45 is the frame width of your filter button 
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,btn2, nil] animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: tried with negative value like '-(self.view.frame.size.width - 130)' still in same place like attached image in question